# Ubuntu C++ UDP package doesn't arrive

Tags: c++, sockets, c++11, ubuntu

I'm want to tinker a bit with c++ and sockets, so I've copied an example server/client to test it. I've got it compiled, but the server doesn't receive any message.

### The client:

```
/* UDP client in the internet domain */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <iostream>

void error(const char *);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sock, n;
   unsigned int length;
   struct sockaddr_in server, from;
   struct hostent *hp;
   char buffer[256];

   if (argc != 3) { 
                printf("Usage: server port\n");
                exit(1);
   }
   sock= socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (sock < 0) error("socket");

   server.sin_family = AF_INET;
   hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
   if (hp==0) error("Unknown host");

   /*bcopy((char *)hp->h_addr, 
        (char *)&server.sin_addr,
         hp->h_length);*/
   memcpy((char *)hp->h_addr, 
        (char *)&server.sin_addr,
         hp->h_length);
   server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
   length=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
   printf("Please enter the message: ");
   //bzero(buffer,256);
   memset(buffer, 0, 256);
   fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
   n=sendto(sock,buffer,
            strlen(buffer),0,(const struct sockaddr *)&server,length);
   if (n < 0) error("Sendto");
   n = recvfrom(sock,buffer,256,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &length);
   if (n < 0) error("recvfrom");
   write(1,"Got an ack: ",12);
   write(1,buffer,n);
   close(sock);
   return 0;
}

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}
```

### Server:

```
/* Creates a datagram server.  The port 
   number is passed as an argument.  This
   server runs forever */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int sock, length, n;
   socklen_t fromlen;
   struct sockaddr_in server;
   struct sockaddr_in from;
   char buf[1024];

   if (argc < 2) {
      fprintf(stderr, "ERROR, no port provided\n");
      exit(0);
   }

   sock=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
   if (sock < 0) error("Opening socket");
   length = sizeof(server);
   //bzero(&server,length);
   memset(&server, 0, length);
   server.sin_family=AF_INET;
   server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
   server.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));
   if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server,length)<0) 
       error("binding");
   fromlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
   while (1) {
       n = recvfrom(sock,buf,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,&fromlen);
       if (n < 0) error("recvfrom");
       write(1,"Received a datagram: ",21);
       write(1,buf,n);
       n = sendto(sock,"Got your message\n",17,
                  0,(struct sockaddr *)&from,fromlen);
       if (n  < 0) error("sendto");
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

As a port I use 1337 and as the IP for the cleint i tried 127.0.0.1 and localhost. After I wrote a message both programs didn't do anything for ~15 min then I closed the terminals.
I used google but didn't find anything (but I'm not sure what I should search).

Comment: Might be unrelated to your problem, but `fromlen` should really be set every time in the loop before calling `recvfrom`.

Comment: And why are you using `write` to print to standard output? Why not simply use e.g. `puts` or `printf`?

Comment: Can you see your data using `tcpdump`?  Are there `iptables` rules blocking the communication?

Comment: Try using `netcat` also known as `nc` as either the client or the server... as client `echo Hello | nc -u 127.0.01 1337` or as a server `nc -u -l -p 1337` to halve your problem. https://www.sans.org/security-resources/sec560/netcat_cheat_sheet_v1.pdf

Comment: @Joachim I have only change things to make it compile I only wantet to see if it works (which it doesn't).

Comment: @Mark The server works fine but the client don't seem to send correctly as netcat does not get anything either.

Comment: This should be tagged C instead of C++, because the code presented is pretty much C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the client, you're copying `&server.sin_addr` into `hp->h_addr`, but you should do it the other way around.
(`memcpy` takes its source and destination parameters in the reverse order compared to `bcopy`.)

This means that you're using an uninitialised address and sending your packet to some random place.

It should be

```
memcpy((char *) &server.sin_addr, 
       (char *) hp->h_addr,
       hp->h_length);
```